# Windows doesn't detect audio CD

Tags: windows, audio, compact-disc

I have an old music CD, which is a home-made demo from 2000 or 2001. When I insert the disc, Windows doesn't detect it at all. I can't open it through "My Computer" and foobar2000 doesn't seem to detect that there's audio on it.

I'm guessing the content of the CD has deteriorated to the point where it's basically unplayable, but is there any way for me, using a Windows 7 system, to extract something useful out of it?

It holds a great nostalgic value with me.

Comment: does it work on other devices?

Comment: you may be able to make a raw image of the cd (byte by byte, configure to ignore false reads, etc..) then use this image for forensics. I have bad experiences when trying to recover the cd itself directly...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other devices to test it on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the disk to another computer, or attempt to clone your CD using Nero. Or copy the disk using cmd. Instructions here http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000823.htm.

But if the result is CRC (cyclic redundancy check) error, I believe there's nothing else we could do.